# Is it possible to fix a vector layer after I badly georeferenced a map?

Tags: qgis, vector, open-source-gis, georeferencing

Sorry in advance if I missed another question on this topic. I searched for everything I could think of, but I didn't find anything with a solution to my problem.

I am quite new to GIS tools and recently georeferenced a map of Germany. I didn't notice that I did a poor job on it though and although in some parts it is correct other's are way off. The problem I have now is that I created a vector layer with line objects based on the wrong georeferencing I did on the map.

I know I can fix the original georeferencing quite easily, but is there a way though to fix the vector layer more or less automatically? Is there any way I can somehow adjust the position of the objects in my vector layer according to the new georeferencing of that map? I would very much like to avoid having to manually create all those line objects again, but don't know how I could possibly fix it otherwise.

Thanks a lot to anyone who can help me with this, it's much appreciated! :)

Edit: I forgot to mention, I am using Quantum GIS 1.8, but if it was possible with any other Freeware I'd be open to try that

Comment: you don't mention what tool you used or would like to use. That will be a neccessary addition to your question

Answer (score 0):

In QGIS select your vector layer in the layers panel, then toggle editing mode. You can do this by selecting the pen icon in the tool bar or by right clicking on your layer and selecting Toggle Editing. Then select the Move Features tool which is to the right of the pen icon in your tool bar. You should then be able to select and move individual features within the layer by clicking and dragging them to the desired locations.

Comment: almost forgot, when you are satisfied with your edits click the disk icon to save them or simply click the pen icon and choose Save Edits. More info here: http://docs.qgis.org/html/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html

Comment: I think the OP is asking about moving all the points *en masse*, which while possible (CTRL-A, drag little-by-little) ..I think a desirable result could be elusive. :/